# coefficients extracted by effects package in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

Consider this logistic regression:

```
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
log_reg_mtcars <- glm(am ~ vs*wt +vs*mpg, family = "binomial", mtcars)
```

I tried using the effects package to extract some coefficients from the model:

```
as.data.frame(effect("vs", log_reg_mtcars)) 

NOTE: vs is not a high-order term in the model
  vs       fit       se       lower     upper
1  0 0.3957869 2.916877 0.002150238 0.9950031
2  1 0.0336822 2.181009 0.000484832 0.7146704
```

Could anyone explain why the coefficients/standard error for `vs` given by this code are different. Or in other words, what is the effects package doing?

```
as.data.frame(summary(log_reg_mtcars)$coef)[2,1:2]

     Estimate Std. Error
vs1 -40.70047   40.53197
```

Comment: I think this one should be left open; true, it's about `R` but the content is inherently statistical